# Is possible send sms from background with iOS 10?

Tags: ios, background, sms

I have an app in Objective-c and I use CoreBluetooth to connect a device. Then while I send the app to background, I can push the button of the device and do call to a server, but I don't know if I could send an SMS without user interaction like send the action to a server.
Is it possible? If yes.. how?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but you will need to use a 3rd party SMS service via an API as you cannot invoke the UI prompt the user to send an SMS.

Comment: but the third party is using internet connection? Or is a private api? I want upload this app to apple store...

Comment: The third party solution would have an internet accessible api. The SMS will come from a number you obtain from the provider, not the user's number. You will pay a fee per SMS you send.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't send sms without user's interaction / permission.